# Counting the number of missing values in specific columns for each ID number

Tags: stata

[Please see image for picture of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UDhy.png)
I want to count the number of teachers that each student had (which might be between 1 and 3).

The form tutor column gives the initials of the form tutor. Each student has a unique ID (e.g. ID = 1 is one student, but due to conversion to long format it appears 4 times). Students may have had between 1 and 3 teachers. I want a variable that tells me the number of teachers for each student (ID).

I'm expecting this to be something like counting the number of missing values in "Form Tutor 1" plus the number of missing values in "Form Tutor 2" plus the number of missing values in "Form Tutor 3". Then subtracting this from the number 3.

Comment: Please read and act on the Stata tag wiki https://stackoverflow.com/tags/stata/info to find out how to show data examples.

Answer (score 0):

In your data example, it seems that something like

```
egen teachers = rownonmiss(Form_Tutor*), strok
```

will get you the answer you want.